# Redefine position and size of existing textbox using Word VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have created textbox in Word 2019.
Name of textbox is "A1001".
Textbox has position "Left=37 and Top=155".
Size of textbox is "Hight=18 and Weight=100".
This parameters can be seen in Development-Property.

I would like to use VBA and by code redefine position and size of "A1001" if/when I again open same document.

I don't want to delete textbox and create new one but simply redefine it!

Can someone help?

Thank You!

Comment: I guess `Weight=100` is a typo. Is it `Width=100`?

Comment: Yes, sorry... You are right.

Answer (score 0):

- Get the textbox object refence with `Shapes()`

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub ReshapeTextBox()
    Dim oShp As Shape
    Const SHP_NAME = "A1001"
    On Error Resume Next
    Set oShp = ActiveDocument.Shapes(SHP_NAME)
    On Error GoTo 0
    If oShp Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Can't find " & SHP_NAME
    Else
        With oShp
            ' Change location and size, modify as needed
            .Left = 30
            .Top = 30
            .Height = 36
            .Width = 200
        End With
    End If
End Sub
```

*Microsoft documentation:*

> [Document.Shapes property (Word)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.document.shapes?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vbawd10.chm158007358)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue)

Comment: Great, thank You "taller" very much!

Comment: P.S.     Can you "taller" please give me a tip how can I separate elements of 2.nd page from 1.st page?

Comment: Please edit your post to share the detail about `separate elements`.

Comment: I have more pages in Word document, let say three. On each page I have ten elements (textboxes and comboboxes).  Now..., I will define in VBA position and size on first page of each element and that is fine. But if I want to define in VBA elements of second page, should I also define which page is it (because .TOP = 30 is only for first page..., what should be for secon page..., should be .TOP = 30 + somethin or not?) ?  Or is it every element defined acording to his anchor? Sorry to bother your ...

Comment: You can disregard the page number. The Top and Left represent the relative distance from the top-left corner on each page.